# Mysql делает 2 одинаковых записи

Tags: mysql, lamp

Имеется скрипт сообщений, все работает на `LAMP` - сервере. При умеренных нагрузках записи `INSERT` (сообщения от пользователей) задваиваются. Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Почему это происходит? Использую `PDO` в частности `prepare` -> `execute`. 
Может ли быть из-за блокировки таблицы при `insert/select`? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Происходит это, вероятно, потому, что структура не требует явно  (уникальным индексом) уникальности записи - только в таких условиях может появиться две идентичные записи. MySQL не станет вставлять две записи, если в запросе вставляется одна - значит, код на PHP по некоей причине выполняет два инсерта. Ищите причину в скрипте. Возможно, чем-то поможет general log - хотя вряд ли...

Comment: Если задваивается - значит вы два раза запись вставляете. тут без вариантов. А вот почему это происходит - надо смотреть ваш код. Есть ли защита от повторной отправки запроса браузером (браузеры иногда повторяют запросы такие моменты надо отлавливать), особенно если передача идет методом GET

Comment: @Mike, скрипт отрабатывает хорошо днем, когда нагрузка небольшая, работа происходит через POST запрос. Сообщения реализованы в приложении

Comment: @Akina, может ли это быть из-за Apache? Ибо так же зависает на это время Apache.

Comment: что значит "зависает". если он медленно отвечает, то клиент запросто может переотправить запрос второй раз, потому как увидит что таймаут какой нибудь истек ... тем более смотрите логи и убеждайтесь, что клиент не присылал одно и то же дважды.

Comment: @Mike, смотрел логи, уровень логов error, все отлично. Нет пользователи не отправляют повторно, т.к. сам отправлял сообщение и оно задвоилось

Comment: Вы не поняли, вы может как пользователь и жмете "отправить" один раз, но браузер или приложение в случае таймаута может сам повторить операцию, вы как пользователь этого даже не заметите. при этом в access_log будет явно видно два обращения ...

Comment: @Mike, хорошо, спасибо понижу лог-левел и посмотрю. Спасибо

Comment: В общем по хорошему клиент должен сформировать какой нибудь заведомо уникальный id сообщения и передавать его вместе с сообщением. А сервер должен убеждаться, что он еще не записывал сообщения с таким id. И если записывал - то вернуть клиенту такой же ответ как если дубля не было, но при этом в БД ничего разумеется не писать